# BulkDocs Api used to save CouchDb document is taking more time compare to put method?

Tags: nosql, couchdb, pouchdb, nano

As we checked in the chrome network tab is shown both Api request and response timing.

Analysis that timings, the bulk docs Api is taking 2x of time to complete the document save in CouchDB. sometimes this 2x time is changed to 3 or 4x it depending on the waiting server response time.

At the same time, The PUT method takes 1/4 time to save the data, and this PUT request is called from another API. It looks like saving records using PUT requests is faster than using BulkDocs API.

Here, I have mentioned the request and response, and the screenshot for your reference.

**BulkDocs Request:**

```
 {"docs":[{"_id":"pfm718215_2_BE1A8AC4-EB53-4C8E-B3F7-5D4FB4329963","data":{"pfm718093_1595329":null,"pfm_718215_id":null,"createdby":52803,"createdon":1665575674775,"lookupname":null,"lookupmail":null,"lastmodifiedby":52803,"lastmodifiedon":1665575674775,"guid":"Xj0JpEofDDy37Z2","name":"test","pfm_718093_1595327_id":null,"display_name":"pfm718215","couch_id":null,"couch_rev_id":null,"pfm718093_1595325":null,"pfm_718093_1595325_id":null,"pfm718093_1595327":null,"pfm_718093_1595329_id":null,"type":"pfm718215","sync_flag":"C","org_id":3}}],"new_edits":true}
```

**BulkDocs Response :**

```
    [{
       "ok": true,
        "id": "pfm718215_2_BE1A8AC4-EB53-4C8E-B3F7-5D4FB4329963",
        "rev": "1-05f3e8e3e96844cb51a8143891b81d16"
     }]
```

**BulkDocs Timings Screenshot** :

[Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdKyU.png)

[Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpT1c.png)

[Timings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWMwQ.png)

**PUT Request** :

```
{"webserviceInput":{"processInfo":{"orgId":3,"userId":52803},"dataParams":{"data":{"pfm718093_1595329":null,"pfm_718215_id":null,"createdby":52803,"createdon":1665569303482,"lookupname":null,"lookupmail":null,"lastmodifiedby":52803,"lastmodifiedon":1665569303482,"guid":"DRtlY2FlKAwVHBq","name":"test","pfm_718093_1595327_id":null,"display_name":"pfm718215","couch_id":null,"couch_rev_id":null,"pfm718093_1595325":null,"pfm_718093_1595325_id":null,"pfm718093_1595327":null,"pfm_718093_1595329_id":null,"type":"pfm718215","sync_flag":"C","org_id":3}},"sessionType":"NODEJS"}}
```

**PUT Response :**

```
    {
         "ok": true,
         "id": "5f1eee08c843d01257c8b698d923fb02",
         "rev": "1-0f67c9b8c2acf7aead7e991e344b04df"
    }
```

**PUT Timings Screenshot** :

[Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3Nxi.png)

[Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5Wqk.png)

[`Timing`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfvR8.png)

**CouchDB version Details :**

Couchdb 3.2.0 and {“erlang_version":"20.3.8.26","javascript_engine":{"name":"spidermonkey","version":"1.8.5"}}